# extract value information from python string

Tags: python, string, split, nlp

I have a string output and I would like to extract the str_data out. That is the value in str_data. Currently I'm using the below code but I think it can be improved on. The below code does not work well with `str_data=['']` and `str_data=['L'm']` as it return list/index out of range error.  str_data contains language information, so it could be empty or contain words like `it's`. Anyway to improve this? Thanks

```
right = result.split("str_data=['")[1]
final = right.split("'], extra='")[0]
```

```
Example 1:
result = TensorSet(tensors={'result': Tensor(shape=['5'], str_data=['ขอคุยด้วยหน่อย'], extra={})}, extra={}
Example 2:
result = TensorSet(tensors={'result': Tensor(shape=['102'], str_data=[''], extra={})}, extra={}
Example 3:
result = TensorSet(tensors={'result': Tensor(shape=[], str_data=['L'm'], extra={})}, extra={}
```

I would like to extract out:

```
example_1_result = 'ขอคุยด้วยหน่อย'
example_2_result = ''
example_3_result = 'L'm'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `TensorFlow(...)` is a string, that will always be formatted with the same arguments, then something like this will work:

`final = result.split(",")[1].split("str_data=")[1].replace("[","").replace("]","")`

Here's a breakdown:

Example input:

`result = "TensorSet(tensors={'result': Tensor(shape=['5'], str_data=['ขอคุยด้วยหน่อย'], extra={})}, extra={})"`

```
>>> result.split(",")[1]
" str_data=['ขอคุยด้วยหน่อย']"
>>> data = result.split(",")[1]
>>> data.split("str_data=")[1]
"['ขอคุยด้วยหน่อย']"
>>> content = data.split("str_data=")[1]
>>> content.replace("[","").replace("]","")
"'ขอคุยด้วยหน่อย'"
>>> final = content.replace("[","").replace("]","")
>>> final
"'ขอคุยด้วยหน่อย'"
```